# Open a userControl within another

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, devexpress

I am using DevExpress DxCheduler, to develop a appointment system. I am using WPF. I have customized Edit appointment form(which is a user control) to add a combobox and a button next to it. The combobox will have a list of customers willing to take an appointment. I want to allow the appointment system user to add a customer if the that customer does not exist, by clicking the button next to the combboox. The button will open up a new window(a user control) with all the fields required to add a customer.

so, my main concern is I have a custom appointment edit form which is a user control. I want to customize the edit form in such a way to add a new button and on click of which I would like to open a new window(user control). I want the exactly same layout as it is for the edit appointment formto be applied to the new add customer form.

Is there a way by which I can call another user control within user control?

Comment: Yes... there is. Provide some details in your question if you want more details in your answer.

Comment: @Sheridan I have updated my question to add more details. Please take a look.